# Visual Studio 2012 won't let me log out of TFS so I can enter new username/password

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I've been trying to disconnect or remove my credentials from a machine because of a conflict. However, whilst connecting to the remote TFS server I was asked for credentials, I cannot find a way to log out of the TFS and log in with new credentials to resolve. How can I drop the credentials or simply log into TFS as a different user. This is driving us crazy as we have a mapping conflict issue.

Currently the login to TFS and on VS is different from that of the machine. Is there a way I can just start again.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check the Credential Manager:
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager

There should be an entry for your TFS and your account. Just delete it and you should be asked again for credentials when connecting VS with TFS.

Comment: I work in a company that uses many domains (a conglomerate), while it logically should, in reality this solution seldom works - TFS sometimes picks this up after days of work at a seemingly random point in time. Most reliable way I found is to reset the password of the currently used domain, clear the TFS cache and restart the computer. I've never tried Sander's solution though.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the solution of Navanod didn't work.

What worked for me was adding the TFS-username to the TFS Server URL separated by the at-sign (@).

As follows:

[image]

Comment: Is the `user` a local account from tfsserver or an AD account? Is your client in the same domain as the tfsserver?

Comment: In my case it regards an AD account and TFS Server resides in same domain.

Comment: But `user` is different to the user you are logged in on the machine you run VS or is it the same? Quite interesting, why to have it that way.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Changing user "made simple" :-)

Comment: Thanks so much. Deleting the user in Credential Manager, deleting caches - nothing worked in VS2012. And then finally your solution did it!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I found for logging out of TFS from within Visual Studio is:

1. In Visual Studio select: *View -> Other Window -> Web Browser*
2. Type in your TFS Server URL in the URL Field (*This means using VS, browse to your TFS url: MyName.visualstudio.com*)
3. Sign out

[image]

Now if you try to connect to your TFS Server, VS would prompt you for Username and Password.